# PHP: issue with strotime

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm trying to have some code show up on the page an hour after the webinar_end_date. I wrote up this code:

```
 <section id="webinar-details">
                    <?php
                    $webinar_date = types_render_field("start-date", array( "raw" => "true"));
                    $webinar_end_date = $webinar_date + ('1 hour');
                    $lp_url = types_render_field("landing-page-url", array("raw" => "true","show_name" => "false" ));
                    if($webinar_end_date < time()){
                        $btn_text = webinar_cta_link_text($lp_url);
                    }else{
                        $btn_text = 'Register Now';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <time id="webinar-start" itemprop="startDate" datetime="<?php echo date("c",$webinar_date); ?>"><?php echo date("M j, Y g:i a",$webinar_date); ?> ET</time>
                    <time class="hide" itemprop="endDate" datetime="<?php echo date("c",$webinar_end_date); ?>"><?php echo date("M j, Y g:i a",$webinar_end_date); ?> ET</time>
                    â€‹<meta itemprop="location" content="Online" />
                    <meta itemprop="duration" content="PT1H" />
                    <?php 
                    if(!empty($lp_url)){
                    ?>
                        <a itemprop="url" class="bob blue-bob" href="<?php echo $lp_url;?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $btn_text;?></a>
                    <?php 
                    }
                    ?>

                        <br />
                        <br />

                    <?php 
                    if(strtotime($webinar_end_date) > strtotime($webinar_date)){
                    ?>           
            <div id="spotlight-markup-1">
                <h3>Get Started</h3>
                <p>Don't know where to start? No worries. Your sales enablement journey starts here.</p>
            </div>
            </section>
                                    <?php 
                }
                ?>

            <?php
```

But it's returning on both before and after the event. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `var_dump(strtotime($webinar_end_date), strtotime($webinar_date))`

Comment: where would I be adding that code? Would it be replacing something already in place?

Comment: It's just debug code - put above your if statement. You need to double check what those values are - chances are they aren't what you expect.